Generators of $\operatorname{NE}(X)$
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $\operatorname{Nef}(X)$ is a rational polyhedron. This implies that the dual $\overline{\operatorname{NE}}(X)$ is a rational polyhedron as well. Suppose we know the generators of $\operatorname{Nef}(X)$, can we figure out the generators of $\overline{\operatorname{NE}}(X)$?
For example, if we had a Mori dream space $X$, then $\overline{\operatorname{NE}}(X)=\operatorname{NE}(X)$. Hence, knowing the generators of $\operatorname{Nef}(X)$ should tell us the generators of $\operatorname{NE}(X).$
This post can be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631289/dual-of-a-rational-convex-polyhedral-cone.

Yes, if you know the generators of a rational polyhedral cone, you (or a software) can figure out the generators of its dual. (This much has nothing to do with algebraic geometry.) Is that the kind of answer you are looking for?

Actually, I wanted to know how, but I found it in Fulton's "Toric Varieties" book. Thanks though. If you know any online tool that can help me with calculating the dual, please let me know .

Thank you so much. Really appreciate it! In this post one can find the general technique: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461094/procedure-to-find-generators-of-the-dual-cone.

One software that can do this is Magma: https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1804 This is not freely available, but it has an online calculator here: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc Beware though that this is limited to "small" calculations. A freely available offline alternative is Normaliz: https://www.normaliz.uni-osnabrueck.de/
